# How to create types array types from unions

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

This question is kind of hard to express for me which might be the reason why I did not find anything on researching.

I'm trying to get a type that ends up with having arrays only. I always want to end up with "one-level" arrays (If arrays of arrays are given, I don't care about the output. This does not happen in my case). So the wanted outcome is the following:

```
type T1 = ForceArray<string> // wanted: string[]

type T2 = ForceArray<string[]> // wanted: string[]
```

I can do this with the following code:

```
type ForceArray<T> = NonNullable<T> extends Array<any> ? T : Array<T>
```

`NonNullable` is used here because in the actual use case, `ForceArray<T>` is used on interface properties which can be optional. This means that `T` can be `undefined`, or in other words `T = U | undefined` where `U` is the actual type (`U = string` or `U = string[]` in the shown examples).

The type definition above works well, except for union types.

```
type T3 = ForceArray<string | string[]> // shows (string | string[])[] but I want string[]
```

Also other union types should be converted to arrays which does not work either:

```
type T4 = ForceArray<number | string[]> // wanted: number[] | string[]

type T5 = ForceArray<number[] | string> // wanted: number[] | string[]
```

In the typescript docs they kind of relate to this by talking about [Distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). But as far as I understand the docs, my code should just work. So obviously I didn't understand the docs correctly.

Is there a way to get the expected behaviour?

---

*Additional information*:

The actual code that produces the output is extremely simple which is the reason why I beleave there should be a solution:

```js
const forceArray = (value) => Array.isArray(value) ? value : [value];
```

This function is used in a context like this, where `obj` can implement any interface (with optional properties):

```js
const convertObjectValuesToArray = (obj) => {
    const newObj = {};
    for (const key of obj) {
        newObj[key] = forceArray(obj[key]);
    }
    return newObj;
}
```

Comment: If NonNullable is needed, please explain why - it is not clear from your implementation what you need the NonNullable for, and the simplest solution to the question you have asked is to delete the NonNullable part.

Comment: @kaya3 you are totally right. Even though the question is answered already, I changed it for other users. I just didn't expect that `NonNullable` was the problem - something with I would have found out if I had made a correct minimal example and omitted the `NonNullable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NonNullable` seems to be the problem here because it disables the distributivity of the generic type similar to brackets `[]`. We could remove it and sorround the returned types with it instead.

```
type ToArray<Type> = Type extends Array<any> ? NonNullable<Type> : NonNullable<Type>[]

type A = ToArray<string>              // string[]
type B = ToArray<string[]>            // string[]
type C = ToArray<string | number[]>   // string[] | number[]
type D = ToArray<string | null>       // string[] | never[]
```

The only problem here is `D` where the return type is `string[] | never[]`. But we can wrap the whole thing into an `Exclude` to get rid of `never`

```
type ToArray<Type> = Exclude<Type extends Array<any> ? NonNullable<Type> : NonNullable<Type>[], never[] | never>

type A = ToArray<string>              // string[]
type B = ToArray<string[]>            // string[]
type C = ToArray<string | number[]>   // string[] | number[]
type D = ToArray<string | null>       // string[]
```